# Serifs used in sans-serif fonts

Tags: fonts, typography, terminology, sans-serif, serif

There are some sans-serif fonts where serifs *are* used sporadically:

[image]

My questions are:

- Are these considered real serifs, i.e. will typeface designers call them serifs or are there other names?
- Is there a name for the phenomenon, meaning using "serifs" in sans-serif" fonts? Can I filter to find these "mix" fonts by using some keyword?
- I found the letters I, T, S, Y, and C using such "serifs". Are there other common "serifs-in-sans" letters?

Comment: Semi-Sans, or Semi-Serif, are common terms used for this mixture.

Comment: @Scott do you think the question has no power to be answered directly? If so, I prefer to delete it...

Comment: No it does.. I just don't have the time to dedicate to it at the moment. So, I left a comment to nudge you to a solution unable to provide detailed information at this time.

Comment: Semi-sans/Semi-serif normally refer to consistent little serifs, like [Agfa Rotis](http://www.fontshop.com/search/?q=rotis), rather than inconsistency as the image. Which font is that?

Comment: @AndrewLeach this one is Anonymous (this is the name :) )

Comment: @Scott could you please convert your comment to the answer? I don't find any other names for that. Also, I don't want to delete the question because I believe it is useful in some degree...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most commonly, **Semi-Sans**, or **Semi-Serif** are used for a typeface which has a mixture of both. I have, on rare occasions, seen **Half-Sans/Serif** used as well.